# Apply a class to table row when checkbox is checked using states

Tags: reactjs, html-table, state, jsx

I have a simple table in parent component where I pass props to child in order to create rows. If the checkbox is checked I want to apply a style to the row and if its unchecked I want to remove it.All checked rows should have the styling. How can I implement this using react states system?

child component

...

```
      render() {
return (
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input className="action-check" type="checkbox"/>
        </td>

        <td>
            <ButtonGroup />
        </td>

        <td>{this.props.name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.date}</td>
    </tr>
)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with hooks:

```js
const [checked, setCheked] = useState(false)

return (
    <tr className={"" + (checked ? "my-css-class" : "") }>
        <td>
            <input className="action-check" type="checkbox" onChange={(e)=> setCheked(e.target.checked)}/>
        </td>

        <td>
            <ButtonGroup />
        </td>

        <td>{this.props.name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.date}</td>
    </tr>
)
```